# How to make server listen and response to many clients at a time?

Tags: python, sockets

How to make server listen and response to many clients at a time using python programming ?
every time i run server then run one client it runs well but when i run another client file with the same code, the server does not deal with them as two client, it complete the as the two clients is only one.
server code

```
import socket
name = "Kyrellos"
CARD_num = 191480
PASS = '084191'
Balance = 7500
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 6060))
s.listen(5)
# print('listening')
cs, address = s.accept()
print(f"Connection established from address {address}")
cs.send(bytes("Welcome to the bank , please enter your card number!", "utf-8"))
client_card_num = int(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())
while client_card_num != CARD_num:
    cs.send(bytes(
        "Card number is not registered, can you try another card number?", "utf-8"))
    client_card_num = int(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())
else:
    cs.send(bytes("please enter your card password !", "utf-8"))
    password = str(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())

while password != PASS:
    cs.send(bytes("password is not correct, can you try again ?", "utf-8"))
    password = str(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())
else:
    cs.send(bytes(f"welcome {name}, enter what do you need please !", "utf-8"))
    print(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())

cs.send(
    bytes(f"your balance is {Balance}, do you need another service ?", "utf-8"))
transaction = str(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip().lower())
if transaction == 'deposit':
    cs.send(bytes(f"enter money amount you want to deposit !", "utf-8"))
    money = int(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())
    Balance = Balance + money
    cs.send(bytes(f"your Balance is {Balance}", "utf-8"))
elif transaction == 'withdraw':
    cs.send(bytes("enter money amount you want to withdraw !", "utf-8"))
    money = int(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())
    while money > Balance:
        cs.send(
            bytes(f"you have not enough balance, can you enter lower amount ?", "utf-8"))
        money = int(cs.recv(2048).decode().strip())
    else:
        Balance = Balance - money
        cs.send(bytes(f"your Balance is {Balance}", "utf-8"))
cs.close()
s.close()
```

client code

```
 import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 6060))
i = 0
for i in range(100):
    print(s.recv(2048).decode().strip())
    s.send(bytes(input(), "utf-8"))
    print(s.recv(2048).decode().strip())
    s.send(bytes(input(), "utf-8"))
    print(s.recv(2048).decode().strip())
    s.send(bytes(input(), "utf-8"))
s.close()
```

Comment: the server should start a new thread to serve a new client, so you can handle more than one

Comment: you have to use module `threading` to run every client in separated thread after `accept()`. OR you would try to use module `select` to check if any client need to execute code but this can be more complex. Minimal working example in my repo `python-examples` on GitHub: [server.py]

Comment: BTW: socket is primitive object and it doesn't care how many data you send - so it may split data into few smaller part or join two data in one data - using only `recv(2048)` can't resolve this problem. You may need to build more complex method to detect if you get correct number of data. You may need to send lenght of data (ie. as 4 bytes) and other side will have to first get 4 bytes to get lenght of data and later use `recv(lenght_of_data)` - see [simple-protocol](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket/simple-protocol)